# passing items from list to controller

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I have a drop-down list of items like below, and I would like to on-click send just the name such as "classes" or "inheritance" , to my controller.

```
<li><a href="#">Pointers</a></li>   
<li><a href="#" class="parent">Classes</a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Shapes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Inheritance</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Polymorphism</a></li>
<ul>
```

My question is should if I should use  Javascript, such as:

```
   <li><a href="#" id="someId" onclick="SomeMethod(this);" > Pointers</a>
```

Then How do i retrieve the element in my function and send to controller?

or can I use use form action ?

Comment: How do you populate the list? Is it dynamically (via php)?

Comment: @timidboy no the list is not dynamic it's just a standard text.

Comment: Why just not like this: `<li><a href="controller/Pointers">Pointers</a></li>` ?

Comment: @timidboy because i need the "string" of whatever is clicked on to do a search against my database with.

Comment: Then why not like this: `<li><a href="controller/search/Pointers">Pointers</a></li>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for javascript...

### HTML:

```
<li><a href="the_controller/the_method/pointers">Pointers</a></li>   
<li><a href="the_controller/the_method/classes" class="parent">Classes</a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="the_controller/the_method/shapes">Shapes</a></li>
  <li><a href="the_controller/the_method/submenu">Submenu</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="the_controller/the_method/inheritance">Inheritance</a></li>
<li><a href="the_controller/the_method/polymorphism">Polymorphism</a></li>
<ul>
```

### Controller:

```
class The_controller extends CI_Controller{
    function the_method($the_word){
        /*do something with $the_word;*/
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure how this works, just giving me an undefined variable in the controller.

Comment: This is [Controllers 101](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html). Please read the CodeIgniter documentation to gather further insight. If you're still stuck, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

```
function SomeMethod(item) {
    var text = item.firstChild.nodeValue;
    ....
    window.location.href = "controller/action/" + text;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a few sentences of explanation that describe how your code answers the question?

Comment: That's the text inside `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

For the example given, with an inline onclick, it could work using innerHTML.

```
<li><a href="#" id="someId" onclick="SomeMethod(this.innerHTML);" > Pointers</a>
```

Comment: And how to I grab "Pointers" in my method, and send it over to my controller? -sorry very new to JS.

Comment: your SomeMethod method needs an argument, ie. function SomeMethod(arg){ /* arg is now = 'Pointers' */ alert(arg); }  then once it is in your method you can transfer it serverside via ajax, or if it is in a HTML form, you can submit the form dynamically, or send it via a window call like timidboy suggested.